# Extracting numbers from a string and calculating percentage in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, grep

I'm running a command line tool which returns results like this -

```
data {   
  metric: 0   
  metric: 1234.5
  metric: 230499
  metric: 234234
} 
data {   
  metric: 0   
  metric: 6789  
  metric: 23526   
  metric: 234634767 
}
```

I'd like to basically calculate (1234.5/6789).....the fraction between the 2nd lines in the 2 results. These numbers can be decimal numbers. The request will always be in that order. Is it possible through grep/sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of your requirements is to use bash commands (`grep`, `sed`, etc.) only. But you have to be aware that you will need something else to do your decimal division. The simplest choice is `bc`.

Here is my suggestion using `grep`, `sed`, `cut` and `bc`. I did not try to compactify it. In theory, you should be able to use only one big `sed` command!

```
./yourProgram | grep metric | sed -n 2~4p | sed -r 's/^\s+//' | cut -f2 -d' ' | sed 'N;s_\n_ / _' | bc -l
```

Let's go through it slowly:

- `grep metric` selects the lines containing "metric"
- `sed -n 2~4p` selects one line out of four, starting from the second line
- `sed -r 's/^\s+//'` suppresses the blank characters at the beginning of the lines. `-r` is the enhanced regex option (to use `\s` and `+`), it is not mandatory but make it look nicer. With MacOS, you should use `-E`
- `cut -f2 -d' '` selects the 2nd field of each lines (the delimiter being a space)
- `sed 'N;s_\n_ / _'` replaces the newline by " / ". Note that we use "_" instead of "/" to be able not to match "/"
- `bc -l` does the operation

Answer (score 1):

Here's an obscure answer: Tcl. The syntax of that output is similar to Tcl syntax, so we can define a procedure named `data` and a procedure named `metric:` and execute that output like a Tcl script. You'd run it like this:

```
tclsh pct.tcl <(the process that produces the output)
```

And the "pct.tcl" script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tcl

set n 0
set values [dict create]

proc data {block} {
    uplevel 1 $block
    incr ::n
}

proc metric: {value} {
    dict lappend ::values $::n $value
}

source [lindex $argv 0]

foreach num [dict get $values 0] denom [dict get $values 1] {
    if {$denom == 0} {
        puts "$num / $denom = Inf"
    } else {
        puts [format "%s / %s = %.2f" $num $denom [expr {double($num) / $denom}]]
    }
}
```

output:

```
0 / 0 = Inf
1234.5 / 6789 = 0.18
230499 / 23526 = 9.80
234234 / 234634767 = 0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        FS=" *\n? *[a-zA-Z]*: *"
        RS="} *\n"
    }
NR<=2 { a[NR] = $3 }
END { print (a[1]/a[2]) }
```

You can use that file with the command:

```
$ awk -f <awk-file> <data-file>
```

Or you can make it executable and call it directly.

`awk` separates the input data into *records* which in turn are separated into *fields*. In the beginning, I carefully craft the record and field separators, so that the interesting metric is in the 3rd field of a record. (The first field is `data {`)

Then for the first and second record, I store the 3rd fields in an array a.

At the end, I print the ratio between the first and second elements of the array.

**Update**: I managed to get it down to 3 lines:

```
BEGIN { RS="} *\n" }
NR<=2 { a[NR] = $6 }
END { print (a[1]/a[2]) }
```

Without setting the field separator, it remains at default. So `$1` is `data`, `$2` is `{`, `$3` is the first `metric:`, `$4` is the first number, `$5` is the second `metric:` and `$6` is the number we want.

Answer (score 0):

`grep`/`sed` cannot perform arithmetic evaluation nor they have the ability to set state variables - so, no, this isn't. Basically, they aren't designed for anything beyond search and replace. This *can* be achieved with stunts coupling them with `head`/`bc`/etc but this is highly inconvenient and fragile.

This is possible with `awk` (the code is tailored to be production-grade so it validates the input and adheres to the DRY principle):

```
function error(m){print m " at line " FNR ":`" $0 "'">"/dev/stderr";_error=1;exit 1;}
BEGIN{brace=0; #brace level
index_=0; #record index
v1="+NaN";v2=v1; #values; if either is not reassigned, the result will be NaN
first_section=0; #1st section ended
second_section=0; #2nd section ended
record_pattern="[[:space:]]*metric:[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]+(\\.[[:digit:]]+)?)[[:space:]]*$";
}
END{if(_error)exit;
if (brace>0){error("invalid:unclosed section");}
if(!second_section){error("invalid:less than 2 sections present")}}
#section start
/^data[[:space:]]+\{[[:space:]]*$/{if(brace>0){error("invalid:nested brace");}brace+=1;next;}
#section end
/^\}[[:space:]]*$/{brace-=1;if(brace<0){error("invalid:unmatched brace")}index_=0;
if(!first_section){first_section=1;next;}
if(!second_section){second_section=1;}
next;}
#record
$0~record_pattern{
match($0,record_pattern,m); #awk cannot capture groups from the line pattern
if(brace==0)error("invalid:record outside a section");
if(index_==1){
  if(!first_section){v1=m[1];}
  else if(!second_section){v2=m[1];}}
 index_++;next;
}
#anything else
{error("invalid:unrecognized syntax");}
#in the very end and if there were no errors
END{print v1/v2;}
```

Though equivalent programs in `perl` and `python` would be much more readable (and thus, maintainable).

Comment: I totally agree with your last sentence: If you need to guard against invalid data, `awk` isn't the tool you want to use. And if you don't need to guard against invalid data, a lot of your script is superfluous.

Comment: @chw21 Why "`awk` isn't the tool"? It is _a_ tool, the program is pretty robust and quite readable. It's just less so than a more modern language.  `sed`/`grep` is, on the other hand, totally _not_ the tool: a robust solution evolved from [styko's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31715524/648265) would be completely over the head of a mere mortal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl solution.

Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt"
data {   
  metric: 0   
  metric: 1234.5
  metric: 230499
  metric: 234234
} 
data {   
  metric: 0   
  metric: 6789  
  metric: 23526   
  metric: 234634767 
}
```

You can use a regex in perl's 'slurp' mode to find the pairs you wish:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -0777 -lne '
@a=/^data\s+\{\s+(?:metric:[\s\d.]+){1}metric:\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/gm;
print $a[0]/$a[1]
'
0.181838267786125
```

The value inside of the braces in `(?:metric:[\s\d.]+){1}`, `1` in this case, will select which pair; `1234.5` and `6789` in this case.